# Call function of body from appbar that is in it's own class

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a class for each "page" of my app, and they all share the same appbar, which is a class of its own.  I have a button on the appbar, and I want it to call a function from whichever page is open.  The function is on each page, and it has the same name on each page.

In my shortened code below, you see the shared `MyAppBar`, and you see 2 pages.  Each of those pages uses `MyAppBar`, and each of those pages has `_myFunction()`.

How can I call `_myFunction()` for each the current page from `MyAppBar`?

```
class MyAppBar {
  setAppBar(context, String title) {
    return new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
          child: IconButton(myIcon),
          onPressed: () => { this should call the current pages _myFunction},),
    ],
  }
}


class _Page1State extends State<Page1>
{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar().setAppBar(context, 'Page 1'),
      body: Container(some content here)
      )
      }

    _myFunction()
    {
    do some stuff;
    }
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2>
{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar().setAppBar(context, 'Page 2'),
      body: Container(some content here)
      )
      }

    _myFunction()
    {
    do some stuff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass those functions.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  MyAppBar({this.pageInstanceFunction});
  var pageInstanceFunction;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      title: Text('My Custom AppBar for #page'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
          onPressed: () {
            pageInstanceFunction();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Here's my Page One

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflow/MyAppBar.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflow/PageTwo.dart';

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(
        pageInstanceFunction: sayHello,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageTwo()));
            },
            child: Text('Page Two'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void sayHello() {
    print('Hello from PageOne');
  }
}
```

And Page Two

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflow/MyAppBar.dart';

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(
        pageInstanceFunction: sayHello,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Text('Page Two'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void sayHello() {
    print('Hello from PageTwo');
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great!  I never knew you could pass an entire function like that.